# How can you display a MessageBox dialog in a LinqPad query?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linqpad

When running/debugging, calls to MessageBox, or Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox hang without showing any dialog.  I think it's being blocked, but see no examples on how to resolve this.

Comment: It shouldn't be blocked. Does the following work for you? http://share.linqpad.net/942ift.linq

Comment: Another option is to use Console.ReadLine() or Util.ReadLine()

Comment: If the answer is useful, please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

I am providing you with step by step instructions, I hope it helps:

### Preparation

You need to **add a reference** by pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> in the LinqPad editor. The query property dialog opens.

There, use <kbd>Add...</kbd> to add the assembly `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` and switch to the tab **Additional Namespace Imports**. Type `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and close the dialog by clicking <kbd>OK</kbd>.

**Note:** Although we are using the DLL from VisualBasic, we can utilize it in **C#** without any limitations. Since it is compiled in .NET it can be used by any .NET language. So the instructions in this answer apply to C#, but in the same way one could use it in VB.NET (just use the language dropdown in Linqpad to make your choice).

---

### General usage

Finally, you can use it as follows:

```cs
void Main()
{
    Interaction.MsgBox("Hello"); 
}
```

**Note:** The Microsoft.VisualBasic works with C# as well as with VB.NET, however this example is using the `C# Program` setting.

Be aware that if you're using multiple monitors, then the messagebox might appear on a different monitor and is not showing in the foreground, so you might not notice it.

I recommend that you force displaying it in the foreground this way:

```cs
Interaction.MsgBox("Hello", MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground);
```

But you can't force it displaying on a specific monitor.

---

### Buttons and other parameters

If you need to know more about the parameters, like title, buttons to display etc., you can look **[here at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.msgbox(v=vs.110).aspx)**.

For example, to display an **Abort, Retry, Ignore** dialog with *Retry* as default button (*DefaultButton2*), you can use:

```cs
MsgBoxResult result =
    Interaction.MsgBox(Title: "Critical Error", Prompt: "Cannot read file",
        Buttons: MsgBoxStyle.MsgBoxSetForeground | MsgBoxStyle.AbortRetryIgnore     
                 | MsgBoxStyle.Critical | MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2);
```

Likewise, to set other buttons as default: *Abort* would be *DefaultButton1* while *Ignore* would be *DefaultButton3.* You may only specify one of them, if you don't specify it, then *DefaultButton1* is assumed.

---

### Checking the result

After the user has clicked, you can query the variable `result` to find out which button was clicked (MsgBoxResult enumeration), i.e.

```cs
if (result==MsgBoxResult.Retry)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Retrying...");
}
```

**Hint:** In **LinqPad** you can also add **aliases for namespaces**. If you don't like to type `Interaction.MsgBox` each time, you can press <kbd>F4</kbd>, go to tab **Additional Namespace Imports**, enter there `Dlg=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction` and close the dialog by clicking <kbd>OK</kbd>.
Then you can use `Dlg.MsgBox(...)` instead of `Interaction.MsgBox(...)`.

---

More LinqPad-related stuff in StackOverflow can be found
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60743368/1016343) and
[there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12006038/1016343)

Answer (score 3):

you can also do this:

```
Util.RawHtml("<script>alert('hello world');</script>").Dump();
```

Answer (score 3):

below code works for me, I am on LINQPad 7.

[image]

the 'issue' I have is when I run LINQpad on my 2nd monitor, the popup dialog always shows on my main monitor. (feels like it's blocked, when I forgot it)

the code is copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/63101136/2055187